# jQuery's "on" and "off" in pure native javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, native

I'm looking for a way to represent the "on" and "off" capabilities of jQuery in pure JavaScript code.

For example:

```
jQuery("my_selector_here").on("click", function(){
     // some code here...
})
```

Should be represented in the most (total) accurate way, something like:

```
myobj.fn.on = function(){
     // pure javascript code here...
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried just looking at the jquery.js and doing a find?

Comment: `on` is an event listener, so check out [`AddEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Comment: @Jai http://i.imgur.com/OpFcp.jpg

Comment: @TheCuBeMan HaHaHa so you love it _satan_....;)

Comment: @Archer I don't think you can add event listeners to a collection without looping over the elements. And I'd highly recommend using `addEventListener` over `onclick`.

Comment: https://gomakethings.com/removing-an-event-listener-with-vanilla-javascript/

Answer (score 6):

The most native approach is using the DOM's `Element.prototype.addEventListener` method. Which looks pretty straight forward like

```
elem.addEventListener('click', function( event ) {
}, false);
```

That is, beside some other magic, what jQuery will call underneath. The biggest issue libraries deal with, is that old'ish Internet Explorer had a different syntax for adding events on Elements. Those used the `elem.attachEvent` method, which had some slight differences.

Naively spoken, we could just add to the `Elements.prototype`. For instance

```
Element.prototype.on = function( name, callback ) {
    this.addEventListener( name, callback, false );
};
```

..and then we can use it like

```
document.body.on('click', function() {
    // code
});
```

Ref.: [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener), [jQuery .on](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L776)

Comment: The representation of the "on" function is relatively easy to understand and implement. What about representing the "off" function on jQuery?? If I remember correctly, the "off" function kills all types of binds on the current element...